# Player movement by touch input on x axis but dont affect other axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make player movement by touch input on the x-axis which I did, but it locks Y and Z axis of movement.

if there is a way to make something like vector3(Touch x axis, dont change,dont change)

This code is working but it locks player for all axses;

```
 void Update()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount == 1 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {

            Vector3 target = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, yAxis, zAxis));
            character.transform.Translate(Vector3.MoveTowards(character.transform.position, target, speed * Time.deltaTime) - character.transform.position);

        }

        if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            Vector3 target = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, yAxis, zAxis));
            character.transform.Translate(Vector3.MoveTowards(character.transform.position, target, speed * Time.deltaTime) - character.transform.position);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Instead of `Input.mousePosition.x`, maybe use `Input.GetTouch(0).position` instead?

Comment: The part with player following touch is working, but i need touch not to affect Y and Z axis.

Comment: When i  move finger i just want  X to change not Y or Z

Comment: I see. So maybe change `yAxis` and `zAxis` to `character.transform.position.y` and `character.transform.position.z`?

Comment: I tried that. Player Just start flying randomly.